# How to prevent continuous website visiting proactively?

Tags: apache, nginx

I found my httpd processes were using a lot of resources in 'htop' (while my page view is actually low and my webserver has 4 CPU with 4G RAM), so I tried to find out what was happening.

Then I found there is an IP kept visiting my site via httpd access log.

After I blocked this IP, my web server was back to normal.

However, I found the problem after my server was in heavy load, which already caused a lot of connection rejections earlier. Therefore my questions are:

(1) What kind of visiting is this? From the rate of the visiting, it's definitely not a human. I looked up this IP, it's from Neitherland, no other information.

(2) What if they change the IP to visit my site like this again? Any way to prevent this kind of visiting proactively?

Comment: I think what you need is one of those: dedicated firewall, dedicated intrusion prevention or intelligent dedicated load balancer, with black and white listing. It would be good to know your sizing, how many requests are "normal". Also I suggest nginx over Apache, it speeded up my website by factor 3 and can handle a huge bigger amount of connections.

Comment: Yes I am using nginx already. My page view is so low that only 1k-2k per day. Most of the requests are not "normal" especially from the same IPs.

Comment: Why you tag the question apache? 2k request per day? It's ~1 request per minute. That's very close to zero ;) Very unclear question. Consider asking on webmasters' or superuser'.

Comment: Ok, I added nginx to the tag. Even if I have nginx, I don't know why my httpd processes are still quite active. I do have a lot of posts (over 500k posts because they are generated by programming). I think there are a lot of search engine crawling.